# Mock SQL shell simulator in Java

Tags: java

I want to simulate a mock SQL shell in Java. The idea is we type a line of text and terminate it with `;` and press enter the line is printed back on the console.

This should be able to take multiline text and once there's a `;` and carriage return it should print out the text.

This is my code:

```
while(true){
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(";");
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
         if(scanner.nextLine().endsWith(";")){
            builder.append(scanner.nextLine());
            break;
          }else{
            builder.append(scanner.nextLine());
          }

          }
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
        }
```

This doesn't work, as it never exits the inner while loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*FYI:* `nextLine()` reads *lines*, not *tokens*, so the delimiter isn't being used by your code.

You need to use `next()` to read tokens, and as you've now realized, you need some condition to end the loop.

A common way to end shells is the `exit` command.

Since you want your statements to end with `;` and carriage return, you need to adjust your delimiter for that. To be more lenient, allow spaces after the `;` (regex: `\h` horizontal whitespace character), and match linebreaks, not just carriage returns (regex: `\R` any Unicode linebreak sequence).

Also, you need to create the `Scanner` *outside* any loops.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(";\\h*\\R");
for (;;) {
    System.out.print(">");
    if (! scanner.hasNext())
        break;
    String stmt = scanner.next();
    stmt = stmt.replaceAll("(?mU:^\\s+\\R)|(?U:\\s+$)", ""); // remove blank lines and trailing spaces
    if (stmt.equals("exit"))
        break;
    System.out.println("Received command: " + stmt);
}
System.out.println("Done!");
```

*Sample Output*

```
>test;
Received command: test
> This is a

multi-line test

with blank lines

          ;
Received command:  This is a
multi-line test
with blank lines
>
;
Received command: 
>exit;
Done!
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check if every line contains `;`? If it does, append relevant value and break out of the loop.

```java
while(true){
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                if (line.contains(";"))
                {
                    String[] parts = line.split(";");
                    if (parts.length > 0)
                    {
                        builder.append(parts[0] + ";");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        builder.append(";");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
        }
```